17. In Z[i], show that 3 is irreducible but 2 and 5 are not
Suppose $3=ab$, where $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ are nonunit. Then 9=d(3)=d(a) d(b),  so that d(a) =3. But there are no integers such that $a^2 + b^2 = 3$. We observe $2=-i(1+i)^2$ and  $5=(1+2i) (1-2i)$.

Better write $2 = (1-i)(1+i)$ . You already solve the problem. Is there any question?

The question should be in the body, not just in the title. Also, you should explain what the $d$-notation is.

$\Bbb Z[i]$ is a Euclidean ring, so irreducible and prime are equivalent properties.

This is a duplicate,  $-1.$

On $2$ and $5.$  Since they can be factored (in more than one way),they're not irreducible.
A little theory,  I'm sure was covered in your course or whatever,  since you have a PID, the irreducibles are the Gaussian primes.
On $3,$ let's write $$3=(a+bi)(c+di).$$
Then, taking norms $$9=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2).$$
So since $9$ only factors as $1\cdot 9$ and $3\cdot 3,$  we're pretty limited.
So you have some diophantine equations.
$a^2+b^2=9$ results in the factorization  $1\cdot 3.$
Meanwhile $a^2+b^2=3$ has no solutions.
More generally,  a Gaussian prime that is a prime is $3\pmod 4,$ by a theorem.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.
